# Map function to list in Mathematica

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to map this function `(1 - num2/num1)*100` to a list. I used the command below, but the command does not work. Can anyone help?

```
length = Quantity[List[45, 66, 74.6, 45, 34, 34.4], "Meters"]
```

The function is:

```
(1 - #[[1]]/#[[2]])*100 & /@ length
```

for example1: `(1-45/no num)*100 = empty`

for example2: `(1-66/45)*100 = 46.66`

for example3: `(1-74/66)*100 = 12.12`

&...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example has an error: 1-66/45 is negative (so 66/45-1 ?). I guess you want to use `BlockMap` for this:

```
list = List[45, 66, 74.6, 45, 34, 34.4];
length = Quantity[#, "Meters"] & /@ list;
BlockMap[(#[[2]]/#[[1]] - 1) 100 &, length, 2, 1] // N
```

results into

```
{46.6667, 13.0303, -39.6783, -24.4444, 1.17647}
```

Or use `Ratios`:

```
(Ratios[Quantity[List[45, 66, 74.6, 45, 34, 34.4], "Meters"]] - 1.0) 100
```

Comment: Thank you SHuisman, for help.